# Redirecting recordtypes and de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm getting an error on my Visualforce page: Attempt to de-reference a null object when using the following page action and controller method.

In the query, some older records that use different layouts are only returning the id and not the RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name from the query. But even when I get RecordType.Name= 'New Account Summary' successfully I get the same error. What could be causing the error?

```
action="{!redirectCREPage}"
```

Debug shows the following path:

- TEST2a mytype is : New Account Summary
- TEST3a mytype is : New Account Summary
- TEST3c mytype is : New Account Summary
- TESTXception mytype is : New Account Summary

  ```
   public PageReference redirectCREPage() {
  PageReference pageRef = null; 
   Account_Summary__c type = null;
   List<Account_Summary__c> types = [Select id, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name from Account_Summary__c where id=:this.AccountSummary.Id];         
   if (types.isEmpty()==false) {
       type=types[0];
       }  if (type.RecordTypeId != null) {          
   String mytype = type.RecordType.Name;
   System.Debug('TEST2a mytype is : ' + type.RecordType.Name );                
      try {               
          System.Debug('TEST3a mytype is : ' + type.RecordType.Name );
           if(type.RecordType.Name.equals('New Account Summary'))             
          { 
              System.Debug('TEST3c mytype is : ' + type.RecordType.Name );
              pageRef.setRedirect(true);
          }
          else 
          {
              System.Debug('TEST4a mytype is : ' + type.RecordType.Name );
              pageRef = new PageReference('/' + this.AccountSummary.Id);
              pageRef.getParameters().put('inline', '0');
              pageRef.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
              pageRef.setRedirect(true);   
          }
          } catch (Exception ex) { 
              System.Debug('TESTXception mytype is : ' + type.RecordType.Name );
              ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
          }                
          return pageRef;
          }else {  System.Debug('SOQL return RecordTypeId is NULL ' + type.RecordType.Name ); }          
   return pageRef;
   }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is `pageRef` is null. The below statement is giving NullPointer exception.

```
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
```

You have declared, `PageReference pageRef = null;`

But before executing following line, you have not assigned any values.

```
if(type.RecordType.Name.equals('New Account Summary'))             
        { 
            System.Debug('TEST3c mytype is : ' + type.RecordType.Name );
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        }
```

Comment: Added the brackets to the code above. The error still persist.

Comment: @rickmac pageRef is *still* null.

Comment: The VisualForce page opening contains the action to redirect so if I assign the pageRef to the page ( pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/PROD_UW_AccountSummary');
pageRef.getParameters().put('id', this.AccountSummary.Id);                    
pageRef.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');

Then the page starts to loop. So I needed to open the VF page with the action to itself.

Comment: @rickmac thats the separate thing all together how you can handle and that is not related to this NullPointer exception question.

Comment: I think it is related. Looking for some help. In fact I've asked other questions on forum already.

Comment: do you want for `New Account Summary` recordtype it will navigate to standard page layout of the record?